# Strange error when trying to read file from apk instead of androidstudio-emulator

Tags: android, json, file, android-studio, cross-domain

I have an Android /Kotlin App that reads JSON from:
https://www.androdocs.com/files/uploads/original/sample-json-data-1567767983.txt

When I use the exact same app and read from:
http://www.makumaku.de/test.txt

it works from Android Studio Emulator.
But if I test the apk from my mobile, I can read only from the first txt-file. the second -txt files results in a white screen.

-> why is that/how can i make http://www.makumaku.de/test.txt -file be readable on mobile, too? thx

Answer (score 0):

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

was the solution, if someone needs it, too